# ROS2 message filters

Tags: ros2, message-filters, ros-galactic

I'm trying to figure out how to use message filters in ROS2 galactic in python. From this example https://github.com/ros2/message_filters/blob/rolling/test/test_approxsync.py I see that

```
import message_filters
```

should work, but I'm getting a error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module name 'message_filters'
```

Is there a ROS2 package I'm missing? Is there a different way I should be importing and using message filters in ROS2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I was not using the correct path for sourcing setup.bash

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing your own python script using this messages or are you running `test_approxsync.py`?

because if you are running this example it seems that the package has not been properly build by `colcon build` and messages are not created.

if you are creating your own package, show how you add this package to `setup.py` in your package because it can not be properly linked.

Comment: I'm trying to run a script that imports message_filters. I'm sourcing
```
source colcon_ws/install/setup.bash
```
I'm not sure why setup.py would be relevant, what do you think should be in it besides the basic setuptools and package name stuff? This is what I'm calling basic setup.py stuff: <https://www.theconstructsim.com/ros2-tutorials-5-how-to-create-a-ros2-package-for-python-update/ >

Comment: sorry, if you are using not ros libraries, they should appear inside. If you are going to use ROS package in another one, you should add it inside `package.xml` file in `<depend> </depend>` marks. I had to do it when I wanted to use custom message inside my package. Did you do it?